# Как сравнить значения из вектора структур

Tags: c++, vector

Всем еще раз здрасте). Сейчас попробую более дитально описать проблему.
Изучаю с++ порядка 4-5 месяцем. И в основном это как и у всех начинающих ввод вывод в консоле не сложных арефметический действий. Для того что бы хоть как-то увидеть то чему я научился решил попробывать реализовать свои знание с некой графикой. По гуглил "Графические библиотека с++", выбрав SFML и думаю что все могу начал писать типа игру. Она не будет никуда выыносится, так чисто для себя, что бы понять что я вообще могу.

Есть файл ***Map.h*** который считывает файл tmx (xml разметка). В нем есть група обьектов которые хранят значаения x, y, width, height.

```
<objectgroup id="10" name="Слой объектов 1">
  <object id="1" x="14" y="7" width="110" height="148"/>
  <object id="2" x="318" y="178" width="64" height="67" visible="0"/>
  <object id="3" x="415" y="176" width="68" height="70" visible="0"/>
  <object id="4" x="510" y="177" width="66" height="73" visible="0"/>
 </objectgroup>
 <objectgroup id="11" name="Слой объектов 2">
  <object id="5" x="0" y="353" width="131" height="223"/>
  <object id="6" x="2" y="311" width="156" height="37"/>
 </objectgroup>
```

Я сделал структура в которой есть эти 4 параметра.

```
    struct Object
{
    vector <float> obj_x;                    //Начало обьекта по Х
    vector <float> obj_y;                    //Начало обьекта по У
    vector <float> obj_width;                //Длина обьекта по Х
    vector <float> obj_height;               //Длина обьекта по У
};
```

Структуру засунул в вектор.

```
vector <Object> vector_object;
```

И получается у меня что каждый новый тег

```
<object id="6" x="2" y="311" width="156" height="37"/>
```

записывается в структуру, а структура записывается в вектор.
В этом примере у меня получается 6 обьектов. При тесте что и как записалось все хорошо, тоесть:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector_object.size(); i++)
{
    for (int q = 0; q < vector_object[i].obj_x.size(); q++)
    {
        cout << "X = " << vector_object[i].obj_x[q] << endl;
        cout << "Y = " << vector_object[i].obj_y[q] << endl;
        cout << "Width = " << vector_object[i].obj_width[q] << endl;
        cout << "Height = " << vector_object[i].obj_height[q] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n______________\n";
}
```

Так же у меня есть герой, который хранит координаты х и у. Я хочу сделать проверку что бы игрок НЕ могу заходить на координаты обьекта, что-то типо этого:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector_object.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < vector_object[i].obj_x.size(); q++)
        {
            if (user_x > vector_object[i].obj_x[q] && user_x < vector_object[i].obj_width[q])
             {
                 move = false;
             }
        }
    }
```

Но тут проблемма что я не могу сравнить значение из вектора[i] обьекта [q] с координатой игрока. Якобы нет перегруженного оператора сравнения. 
Вот тут мне и нехватает знаний... Подскажите, куда копать, и что читать)

Так же как вариант можно сделать динамический масив, под групу координат отдельный масив, к примеру:

```
float *x = new float[size];
float *y = new float[size];
float *width = new float[size];
float *height = new float[size];
```

но помойму, вектором удобнее пользоватся

Comment: Какой у вас размер поля? При "малом" размере поля, есть смысл сделать двухмерный массив byte (или char или int) с признаком 0 1 есть препятствие или нету, или вообще, тип препятствия заносить в сетку, типа с 0-50 - нет препятствий (дорожка травка и т д), свыше 50 - препятствия. На сетку проэцировать игровое поле и.... Тогда проверкой area[x][y]  - будет поятно есть в этой точке препятствие или нету.

Comment: float  - не удачный тип для сравнения, потому что в результате "калькуляций" мантиса может несовпасть (проблема что 2+2 не равно 4.) возможно вы поймали этот баг. Используйте целочисленные типы. Если уж надо "плавность" внутри клетки, то выделите для клетки 8, 16 или кратное двойке число пикселей (для удобства проверок). Для 8 будет номер клетки поля `x & (0xFFFFFF - 7)` а смещение внутри клетки будет `x & 7`

Comment: @nick_n_a у него нет проверки на равенство

Comment: Это слишком просто что бы так реализовать. Я понял ход вашим мыслей. Но делается с максимальным использованием своих знаний. По моей теории легко изменить карту, добавить новую. Для реализвации вашей теории для каждой карты нужно писать отдельный двухмерный масив.

Comment: тим user_x тоже float. все координаты используют float. текстк ошибки отсутствует оператор \">\", соответствующий этим операндам -- типы операндов: float > std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>"

Comment: @Maksim nick не говорит вам хранить ваше поле в массиве. Храните в xml. Но при считывании формируйте массив, а не вектор структур

Comment: @AntonShchyrov но вектор удобнее и надежнее масива. Я сегодня ночью попробую еще поковырятся. Если не получится буду переделывать(
сам файл https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/game/blob/master/map/Map.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зачем вам в структуре векторы? Из того, что вы написали, структура должна объявляться так

   ```
   struct Object {
       float obj_x;                    //Начало обьекта по Х
       float obj_y;                    //Начало обьекта по У
       float obj_width;                //Длина обьекта по Х
       float obj_height;               //Длина обьекта по У
   };
   ```

   а еще лучше так

   ```
   struct Object {
       int obj_x;                    //Начало обьекта по Х
       int obj_y;                    //Начало обьекта по У
       int obj_width;                //Длина обьекта по Х
       int obj_height;               //Длина обьекта по У
   };
   ```
2. При сравнивании координат нужно проверять условие

   ```
   obj_x < user_x < obj_x + obj_width
   ```

   а не

   ```
   obj_x < user_x < obj_width
   ```

   ```cpp
   for (int i = 0; i < vector_object.size(); i++) {
     Object obj = vector_object[i];
     if (
       user_x > obj.obj_x && user_x < obj.obj_x + obj.obj_width &&
       user_y > obj.obj_y && user_y < obj.obj_y + obj.obj_height
     ) {
       move = false;
       break;  // дальше искать бессмысленно
     }
   }
   ```
3. Этой фразы

   > Но тут проблемма что я не могу сравнить значение из вектора[i] обьекта [q] с координатой игрока. Якобы нет перегруженного оператора сравнения

   я не понял вообще. Будет лучше если вы приведете **точный** текст ошибки

Comment: отсутствует оператор \">\", соответствующий этим операндам -- типы операндов: float > std::vector<float, std::allocator<float>>",

Comment: @Maksim [Никакой](http://cpp.sh/7b6l2) ошибки на приведенном коде я не вижу

Comment: так он и не заходит не в один цыкл.

Comment: @AntonShcyrov Все, всем спасибо. Кажется разобрался))) Опять в который раз моя не внимательность. Проблема была втом что я обьявлял как 
object_vector[i].obj_x а надо object_vector[i].obj_x[i]. И он сравнивал ВЕКТОР и не значение из него.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Ошибкой была моя не внимательность. При попытке сравнивать было vector_object[i].x а надо vector_object[i].x[i]. В первом случаем он пытался сравнить координату персонажа типа float с ВЕКТОРОМ, а нужно было именно со значением из вектора.

Comment: В вашем вопросе этой ошибки не было

Comment: @AntonShchyrov честно говоря, я сам не доконца понял как получилось побороть ошибку))) Но , когда стороний человек смотрит и дает совет начинаешь немного думать по другому. Не зря же говорят что одна голова хорошо а две лучше) Спасибо вам большое за помощь.